# Are there any concerns with using Snowflake as the data repository for a web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Are there any concerns with using Snowflake as the data repository for a web API from an enterprise architecture perspective?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question to be asked is how are you going to use the data. It is not clear what you mean by web API data repository. If you are talking about the API interaction data, then Snowflake is not the right choice for that. You should look for a transactional data store for such use cases. However, from that data , if you want to derive insights and analytics you can ingest the transactional data to Snowflake and build your analytics layer on top of it. But the question will be why would you like to do that, most of the API products have that analytics engine already built in their product.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the API interaction data. You said that Snowflake is not the right choice. Is this because Snowflake is a data warehouse for analytics and not transactional data? Some concerns I've heard are surrounding cost, but do you think performance is also a concern?

Comment: I have mentioned it more from a technical use case perspective. The cost and performance depends on how one is designing the data architecture. Snowflake is a column oriented micro partition based data store. Transactional workloads are not the right use cases for Snowflake or any DWH products.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Rajib!